# nlmeODE does not work when an additional parameter was added to the Theoph model example in R documentation for nlmeODE

Tags: r, nlme

I tried running the Theoph model provided in the R documentation for nlmeODE package with my own dataset and it was able to return the parameter estimates. However, when I added an additional parameter that I wanted to estimate, I received an error message as shown below. Could anyone advise what went wrong and how I could fix this?

---

The example model provided in the R documentation looks like:

```
data(Theoph)
TheophODE <- Theoph
TheophODE$Dose[TheophODE$Time!=0] <- 0
TheophODE$Cmt <- rep(1,dim(TheophODE)[1])
OneComp <- list(DiffEq=list(
dy1dt = ~ -ka*y1 ,
dy2dt = ~ ka*y1-ke*y2),
ObsEq=list(
c1 = ~ 0,
c2 = ~ y2/CL*ke),
Parms=c("ka","ke","CL"),
States=c("y1","y2"),
Init=list(0,0))
TheophModel <- nlmeODE(OneComp,TheophODE)

Theoph.nlme <- nlme(conc ~ TheophModel(ka,ke,CL,Time,Subject),
data = TheophODE, fixed=ka+ke+CL~1, random = pdDiag(ka+CL~1),
start=c(ka=0.5,ke=-2.5,CL=-3.2),
control=list(returnObject=TRUE,msVerbose=TRUE),
verbose=TRUE)
plot(augPred(Theoph.nlme,level=0:1))
```

---

My modified model looks like:

```
group1 <- groupedData(conc ~ Time | Subject,
                  data=myowndata)

OneComp2 <- list(DiffEq=list(
  dy1dt = ~ -ka*y1 + kr*y2,
  dy2dt = ~ ka*y1 - kr*y2 -ke*y2), #I added in a reabsorption rate kr
  ObsEq=list(
    c1 = ~ 0,
    c2 = ~ y2/CL*ke),
  Parms=c("ka","ke","kr","CL"),
  States=c("y1","y2"),
  Init=list(0,0))

Model2 <- nlmeODE(OneComp2,group1)

nlme2 <- nlme(conc ~ Model2(ka,ke,kr,CL,Time,Subject),
                  data = group1, fixed=ka+ke+kr+CL~1, random = pdDiag(ka+CL~1),
                  start=c(ka=0.5,ke=-2.5,kr=-2.5,CL=-3.2),
                  control=list(returnObject=TRUE,msVerbose=TRUE),
                  verbose=TRUE)
```

---

The error message reads:

```
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```